# Is there a way to disable hover on a certain div/element?

Tags: html, css

Here's the live preview : http://cyberview.com.my/tender/tender-listing

On the page there's this div below:

```
 <div class="tiles--medium-bottom">
       <img src="http://cyberview.com.my/images/default-source/default-album/15faf31fa9819a64c5aa74ff000073ca3c.jpg?sfvrsn=0" alt="Interior Design" title="Interior Design">
          <div class="tiles__content">
               <span class="label">Interior Design</span>
               <span class="tiles__headline">Tender ID: CYBERVIEW-400-10/3/3 (1)</span>
               <span class="tiles__description"><p>Project Name: Proposed Design, Construction and Completion of IDFO Works for Terengganu Digital (Phase 1) at Block F, Ladang Business Centre, Kuala Terengganu, Terengganu Darul Iman for Cyberview Sdn Bhd</p>
                        <p>Closing Date: TBC</p></span>
          </div>
            <span class="tiles__cta">Details <i class="icon-chevron-small-right align-middle"></i></span>
</div>
```

css:

```
 .tiles--medium-bottom {
     transition-duration: 0.5s;
     transition-delay: 0;
     transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.05, 0.5, 1);
     transition-property: color;

     position: relative;
     margin: 10px 0;
     color: #fefefe;
     overflow: hidden;
 }

  .tiles--medium-bottom:after {
     transition-duration: 0.5s;
     transition-delay: 0;
     transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.05, 0.5, 1);
     transition-property: opacity;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     background-color: #00f75e;
     content: '';
     z-index: 0;
     opacity: 0;
  } 

   
    .tiles--medium-bottom:hover {
      color: #404143;
     }
```

When I hover, the description will appear, header and description will change to dark grey. Background colour changes to light green.

I want to disable the hover and show the description without affecting other elements that are using the same class. Basically it will look like this without any hover effects:

[image]

what's the best way to go about to achieve the image above?

Comment: Do you have acces to the CSS files. If so you could just remove the hover effects written for `:hover`.

Comment: I can remove the hover effect, but this is not desirable as it might affect other elements using the same class that I don't know of.

Comment: Can you post the CSS for the hover and  the normal state.

Comment: Can you edit the HTML content ie. add an ID to the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i propose you to add a specific class and manage the style using it

```
<div class="tiles--medium-bottom yourclass">


.tiles--medium-bottom.yourclass: after {
    display: none; }
.tiles--medium-bottom.yourclass:hover .tiles__headline, .tiles--medium-bottom.yourclass:hover .tiles__description, .tiles--medium-bottom.yourclass:hover .tiles__cta {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

please add this class in your css file:-

`.nav-first > li > .nav__link:hover:after, .nav-first > li > .nav__link.is-hover:after {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}`

```
.nav-first > li > .nav__link:hover, .nav-first > li > .nav__link.is-hover {
color: #fff !important;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a unique ID or class to the div and chain it with the CSS of your normal state.

```
<div class="tiles--medium-bottom no-hover">
```

And in your CSS

```
.tiles--medium-bottom.no-hover:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.tiles--medium-bottom,
.tiles--medium-bottom.no-hover:hover {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.05, 0.5, 1);
  transition-property: color;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #fefefe;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tiles--medium-bottom:after,
.tiles--medium-bottom:after.no-hover:hover {
   transition-duration: 0.5s;
   transition-delay: 0;
   transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.05, 0.5, 1);
   transition-property: opacity;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: #00f75e;
   content: '';
   z-index: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}
.tiles--medium-bottom.no-hover .tiles__description {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think my problem right now is that I want to get rid of this fade-in fade out effect when I hover. and just have the description to appear from the start. I can't figure out how to make sure this transition is happening when I hover.